# log4net configuration out of box solution

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am looking into log4net for the first time as I found on the net that it is faster than Enterprise Library provided by Microsoft. I am trying to configure it to log to

1. Sql server
2. File
3. Event log.

Is it out of box or do we need to write code? In Enterprise Library I didn't write any code for this.

I am aware of appenders and did the poc to login to sql,rolling file and event log separately but was not able to identify the fallback mechanism. Is there any way for this e.g if sql log fails it should write to rolling file, if that fails it should write to event log.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was aware of appenders and did the poc to login to sql,rolling file and event log separately but was not able to identify the fallback mechanism. Is there any way for this e.g if sql log fails it should write to rolling file, if that fails it should write to event log. Sorry again for not putting question correctly because in enterprise library we don't have to code for fallback mechanism

Regards, ABB

Answer (score 1):

To send logs to a destination you need what log4net calls appenders. In your case all your needs are taken care of by the library out of the box

- [AdoNetAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html): sends event logs to a database. You need to write the query and map the properties of your event to the parameters of the query: this is done in the configuration file.
- [FileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.html): writes to file and is the basis for all file logging. `RollingFileAppender` is a variant that lets you roll your file on some triggers (date or/and size out of the box)
- [EventLogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender.html): writes to the Windows event log

All that remains now is to tweak your configuration in order to find something that matches what you need. For details on how to configure the appenders discussed see [these examples](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

---

Regarding the fallback mechanism there won't be any way to do it without writing code. log4net doesn't let you hook into potential appender errors since its stance is that a logging framework should never cause any change in behavior in its client if it fails. If you need conditional logging branching then it falls on the client to implement it.

Comment: Any idea where I can get sample code for this. I would like 3 appenders as mentioned above.

Comment: There are some ideas in this jira thread: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-1 . You could perhaps implement them in custom appenders

Comment: Hi, I got (https://code.google.com/p/log4netcontrib/wiki/FallbackAppender) link and tried to configure. I was able to fallback from fileappender to Ado net appender(by giving wrong path(drive) of file). But when I kept ado net appender first and created exception by giving wrong table it didn't wrote to fileappender. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: If you have the source for this appender (good find, btw) perhaps you should try and step in the code to see what happens. If you really cannot find the reason for the problem try asking another question

Comment: Hi Samy, Yes will do that, thanks for  the help. Like you suggested in case I am not able to find the reason even after debugging will post new question.-